# failed to update ref ./HEAD.lock Permission denied

Tags: git

When I try to push to my git repository I get this error. The git instance is running on an ubuntu server.

```
failed to update ref
error: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': Unable to create
'/home/git/projectname/./HEAD.lock': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change permissions for Git-repository folder to have full control on it:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER -R /home/git/projectname/
```

and then retry.

Comment: The problem turned out to be the user the remote system used to log in. The user was in the group, but not the owner of the files. Using the correct user fixed this issue. Since it was a permission issue, N0rbert is close enough to earn the answer.